# Copy index value to coloumns where cell value is non zero in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
Index Z1  Z2  Z3 Z4
 A    0   0   1  3
 B    0   2   0  0
 C    2   0   1  0
 D    4   0   3  0
 E    0   0   2  0
```

I want it to look like this

```
 Index Z1  Z2  Z3 Z4
  A    0   0   A  A
  B    0   B   0  0
  C    C   0   C  0
  D    D   0   D  0
  E    0   0   E  0
```

Basically i want to replace non zero values with corresponding index element of that particular row

How can I do like that in simplest possible way

**Edit1**

Is there any way to retain the non zero values along with index value 
For example I want it to be like

```
 Index Z1   Z2   Z3   Z4
  A    0    0    A(1)  A(3)
  B    0    B    0     0
  C    C(2) 0    C(1)  0
  D    D(4) 0    D(3)  0
  E    0    0    E(2)  0
```

If not exactly in the same format it would be acceptable but I would prefer to have the number as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with `axis=0`:

```
df = df.where(df == 0, df.index.to_series(), axis=0)
```

Or:

```
df = df.mask(df != 0, df.index.to_series(), axis=0)

print (df)
      Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
Index            
A      0  0  A  A
B      0  B  0  0
C      C  0  C  0
D      D  0  D  0
E      0  0  E  0
```

For your EDIT - use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with [`radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html) for add from right:

```
df1 = df.astype(str).add(')').radd('(').radd(df.index.to_series(), 0)
df = df.where(df == 0, df1)
print (df)
         Z1    Z2    Z3    Z4
Index                        
A         0     0  A(1)  A(3)
B         0  B(2)     0     0
C      C(2)     0  C(1)     0
D      D(4)     0  D(3)     0
E         0     0  E(2)     0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked fine.Can you please go over Edit 1 and tell if its possible

Answer (score 1):

This would also do the job, in a similar manner:

```
df[df>0] = df.index.tolist()
```